# Editing a citation style (verbose-ibid)

Tags: biblatex

a lot of questions are asked regarding more or less my topic, but I'm unable to find answers. I'm using overleaf and I would like to be able to generate the code of the citation style `verbose-ibid` to be able to edit it. I started using Latex a few days ago and don't know anything about it, but I am quite ok modifying a Zotero style for instance.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[greek, french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}   
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry} 



%Bibliographie
%----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
   author = {Author, A.},
   year = {2001},
   title = {Title},
   publisher = {Publisher},
 }
 \end{filecontents}

 \begin{document}

 \footcite{key}

 \printbibliography

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post the code example directly in your question and do not link to third-party sites. Also please try to make your code fully self-contained so that other people can run it without additional files (we don't have your `Biblio.bib`). Also, please try to remove code that is unreated to the sisue at hand (for example the `\newcommand{\titre}` stuff, many of the packages you load are also not relevant). See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864.

Comment: Finally, please note that ideally each question on this site should only revolve around *one* specific issue. As such it might not be unreasonable to split your one question up into four small questions.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, my main question, then, would be, how do you find the code of the verbose-ibid citation style.

Comment: I'll have a look at your question shortly, but please note that now your code is *too* minimal. The code should still be compilable when it is copied and pasted, i.e. it must have a `\documentclass` and a `\begin{document}...\end{document}` and a few example citations etc., it just should not have too much stuff. See also the two links in my first comment.

Comment: You may want to customize package options described [here](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/examples/71-style-verbose-ibid-bibtex.pdf) instead of editing the code directly.

Comment: @zyy Unfortunately, the customize options in the package do not allow me to preform the editing I need.

Comment: @moewe, thank you for your patience and your help, it is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for `biblatex` styles can be found in `<style>.bbx` (bibliography style code) and `<style>.cbx` (citation style code).

In your case the relevant files are `verbose-ibid.bbx` and `verbose-ibid.cbx`. You can find these files on your machine with `kpsewhich verbose-ibid.bbx` and `kpsewhich verbose-ibid.cbx`, respectively.

All relevant files are also on CTAN in https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex or http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/ and its subdirectories, and on GitHub in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/ and subdirectories.

You'll find that `verbose-ibid.bbx` immediately sends you off to `authortitle.bbx`. So the first interesting file is `authortitle.bbx`.

`verbose-ibid.cbx` on the other hand contains a complete citation style.

Additional to the style-specific files, you will always want to have `standard.bbx` and `biblatex.def` handy. `standard.bbx` is loaded by all standard `biblatex` styles and `biblatex.def` is loaded by all styles automatically. The `biblatex` documentation is also helpful.

`biblatex` styles are modular and that means that you may have to chase down definitions of the involved macros in several different files.

---

To answer some of the concrete questions from [an earlier version of your question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/456615/2).

1. You can change the *default punctuation* from a full stop to a comma with

   ```
   \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
   ```

   This will also apply to the bibliography at the end, so if you want a different layout there you may have to use `\AtBeginBibliography`
2. Is more tricky, I didn't do anything here because the desired output was not clear to me. I suggest you ask a new question with well-defined desiderata.
3. Could be achieved with the option

   ```
   giveninits=true
   ```

   Again, if the behaviour should be different in the bibliography, you need to do extra work.
4. The `citepages` option could help you here. See the [`verbose-ibid` style documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/71-style-verbose-ibid-biber.pdf). Maybe you want

   ```
   citepages=omit
   ```

   or maybe the more radical `citepages=suppress` or the fancy `citepages=separate`.

Your document could look like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, backend=biber, giveninits=true, citepages=omit]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite[381]{sigfridsson}
ipsum\autocite[200]{spiegelberg}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 1. E. Sigfridsson et U. Ryde, « Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments », in : Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), doi : 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P, p. 381.//2. H. Spiegelberg, « “Intention” und “Intentionalität” in der Scholastik, bei Brentano und Husserl », in : Studia Philosophica 29 (1969), p. 200.]

Comment: I am pouring tears of joy, thank you so much for your time and your help!!

Comment: @Aulus.Persius.Flaccus Glad I could help. And thank you for editing and improving your answer after feedback in the comments.