# How to create biblatex bibliograpy and citation syles

Tags: biblatex, xetex

I currently writing a paper using LaTeX, more specifically XeLaTeX and `biblatex` with Biber because the paper is written in Arabic.

The bibliography and citation style of the journal in which I am going to publish in is not available for LaTeX and I have to create it from the ground up.

How can I create bibliography and citation styles for `biblatex`?

Comment: I edited your question a bit to make it a bit more 'correct': `biblatex` is the bibliography package and the 'language'/environment in which you define the style. Biber is just the 'backend' that reads the data from the `.bib` file. Biber is not directly involved in most style decisions.

Comment: Note that many publishers do not and cannot accept `biblatex` submissions. (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). So before you start writing a full blown `biblatex` style for a journal submission, double check with the editor or other journal staff that they can accept `biblatex`-generated bibliographies in LaTeX submissions.

Comment: Don't worry, i will convert to docx before submitting, as they don't know what is latex in my university

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question that comes up from time to time, but I'm afraid there is no comprehensive tutorial for writing `biblatex` styles at this point.

Some of the introductory materials at [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864) mention a few things that could be interesting to style developers, but there is nothing comprehensive in English. There is a series of two German articles from 2008 by Dominik Waßenhoven in *Die TeXnische Komödie* about his `biblatex` style (https://archiv.dante.de/DTK/PDF/komoedie_2008_2.pdf, https://archiv.dante.de/DTK/PDF/komoedie_2008_4.pdf).  (Note that the articles are more than 10 years old now, many details have changed since then. The overall approach is still the same, but I expect that there will be new, more elegant interfaces for a few things.) See also the discussion at the end of my answer to [Customize biblatex citation style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542415/35864).

If you want to code your own style, the best way to start is to look at the code of the standard styles in

- [`biblatex.def`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
- [`standard.bbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/standard.bbx)

and a base style you like, say,

- [`authoryear.bbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/authoryear.bbx)
- [`authoryear.cbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/bauthoryear.cbx).

See [What is the location of the biblatex citation style files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542043/35864) and [Editing a citation style (verbose-ibid)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/456615/35864) for more details on where to find the style file. See also the first part of [Customize verbose citation style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542604/35864).

You can also look at some of the styles on CTAN, but keep in mind that styles implementing more complex guidelines (like APA or Chicago style) may have to be quite complex to implement the rules to the letter.

The manual documents all commands defined by the `biblatex` core, but it does not document all style decisions and style-level (bibmacro) definitions. Because of its length and structure it is often more useful as a reference to look up what exactly a certain command or option does rather than as a guideline to help you write a style.

A great way to get started is [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864) and you will find countless questions and answers about modifying `biblatex` styles on this site already.

If you get stuck, just ask a new question about the problem you are facing. Please try to make your question about specific one particular bit of the style and include a [concise example document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) as well as clear descriptions of the desired output.

Comment: Turns out it is a bit more complex than csl

Comment: @OssamaNasser I don't know a lot about CSL, but from what I have seen of it I would tend to agree with that statement. CSL styles seem to be a bit more compact. Plus there are many CSL styles out there and documentation seems to be good as well.

Comment: Actually there is a web UI that allows the creation of csl styles without writing a single xml letter

Comment: @OssamaNasser Depending on your conversion route from LaTeX to `.docx` you may actually be able to use CSL. Pandoc has CSL support with pandoc-citeproc. (That's all hearsay, I have never used Pandoc or pandoc-citeproc.)

Comment: I tried and it sux

Comment: However i will try it again but on windows instead of Linux

Comment: @OssamaNasser Ah, bad luck. I can't promise that the experience with `biblatex` will be better, though. You might be OK if your bibliography contains only Arabic works or only English works, but as soon as things are mixed, you probably will have to work around some quirks.

Comment: Thank god my bibliography only contains English works, otherwise I will have to do citations by hand, in fact my university's journal update its citation style to remove mixed languages in the bibliography, now if I have an Arabic work I just add `in Arabic` at the end of it's bibliography otherwise it would have been a nightmare.