# Defining a bibstyle and citestyle for autocite footnote

Tags: biblatex

I'm relatively new to LaTeX with writing assessments (for my study).

I'm trying to set up a template, and so far it looks good to me. But I have absolutely no idea of how to set up my biblatex for my needs (University guidelines).

I'm reading and testing since to 2 days, but I'm feeling completely lost in all this information and different ways to solve problems.

What do I need?

For the citestyle I need a footnote cite with the following:
family name(s) of the author(s), the year (if the year is not defined, the short title) and the page where the cite is located.

So this would be for the `@Book` `KochELT302`:

> Koch, Boolsche Algebra und kombinatorische Schaltkreise, Page 21.

For the bibstyle, I need more information.
I need the Familie-name, the first-name (if multiple authors only the initials), the year, the full title, the edition and the location.

For example the `@Book` `DigitaltechnikFricke2018`

> Fricke, Klaus, (2018), Digitaltechnik Lehr- und Übungsbuch fürElektrotechniker und Informatiker, 8. überarbeitete und aktualisierte Auflage, (Wiesbaden)

I read different articles and also the documentation, and I think I need to renew the macros for the citestyle and define the format I need.

I read this post: [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles)

But how do I know which macro is used in my case?

Thats what I got so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headinclude,footinclude]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=4.5cm,right=2cm,}

\usepackage[babel, german=guillemets]{csquotes}  
\usepackage[
    bibstyle=authoryear,
    citestyle=authortitle,
    autocite=footnote,
    sorting=nty,
    maxcitenames=3,
    mincitenames=3,
    maxbibnames=8,
    minbibnames=8,
    ]{biblatex}
    
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

% Diverse Anpassungen für Literaturverzeichnis und Zitate 
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default} 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{andothers = {et al.}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{nodate = {o.J.}}
    
\title{AKAD-Vorlage}
\author{Author}
\date{August 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage

\section{Test-1}
Test\autocite[Site 31]{KochELT302} \\
Test2\autocite{Gehrke2016} 

\newpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

So, I could need some help or maybe a soft push in the right direction :-)

Here is my bib-file

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Book{DigitaltechnikFricke2018,
  author   = {Klaus Fricke},
  date     = {2018},
  title    = {Digitaltechnik},
  edition  = {{8. überarbeitete und aktualisierte Auflage}},
  location = {Wiesbaden},
  subtitle = {Lehr- und Übungsbuch fürElektrotechniker und Informatiker},
}

@Book{Gehrke2016,
  author   = {Winfried Gehrke and Marco Winzker and Klaus Urbanski and Roland Woitowitz},
  date     = {2016},
  title    = {Digitaltechnik},
  edition  = {{7. überarbeitete und aktualisierte Auflage}},
  location = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
  subtitle = {Grundlagen, VHDL, FPGAs, Mikrocontroller},
}

@Book{KochELT302,
  author   = {Andreas Koch},
  title    = {Boolesche Algebra und kombinatorische Schaltkreise},
  subtitle = {Digitaltechnik - ELT302},
}

@Book{KochELT303,
  author   = {Andreas Koch and Dietmar Möller and Tobias Schubert and Dieter Jäger},
  title    = {Sequenzielle Schaltungen, Schaltwerke und Simulationssoftware},
  subtitle = {Digitaltechnik - ELT303},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:biblatex;}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT:

I edited the text to get it more compact and define more precisely what I need.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm having a hard time understanding the desired output in citations and the bibliography. Is there a chance you could explain the desired output in more detail and show how it would look with a few of your example entries?

Comment: I'm sry. English is not my first language. I try my best to explain my desire format.

Comment: The citation should be in the footnote (best case with autocite) in the following style 
Familiyname, year and if no year available the title, and the source. 

So this would be for @Book{KochELT302}: Koch, Boolsche Algebra und kombinatorische Schaltkreise, Page 21. 

I think this is called havard style?! 

For the bibstyle for @Book{DigitaltechnikFricke2018,
Fricke, Klaus, (2018), Digitaltechnik Lehr- und Übungsbuch fürElektrotechniker und Informatiker, 8. überarbeitete und aktualisierte Auflage, (Wiesbaden)

Hope this helps a little bit more.

Comment: I added the explanation in the main part above for better layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guidelines in [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) are a great start, but if you want to do bigger modifications there will come a point where you have to look at the `biblatex` style code.

As explained in [How to create biblatex bibliograpy and citation syles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/554623/35864), [What is the location of the biblatex citation style files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542043/35864), [Editing a citation style (verbose-ibid)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/456615/35864) you will want to have a look at

- `biblatex.def`
- `standard.bbx`
- `<(bib)style>.bbx`
- `<(cite)style>.cbx`

for the most important definitions (the linked answers contain a few more details about what can be found where and how to find these files in the first place).

Based on your description I came up with the following

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headinclude,footinclude]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[babel, german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    style=authoryear,
    autocite=footnote,
    maxcitenames=3,
    mincitenames=3,
    maxbibnames=8,
    minbibnames=8,
    ]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}

\DeclareListWrapperFormat{location}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  andothers = {et al\adddot},
  nodate    = {o.J\adddot},
}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:label}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{label}}}
    
\newbibmacro*{cite:labeltitle}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \ifboolexpr{   test {\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
                 or test {\iffieldequalstr{labelyear}{nodate}}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:labeltitle}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{DigitaltechnikFricke2018,
  author   = {Klaus Fricke},
  date     = {2018},
  title    = {Digitaltechnik},
  edition  = {8. überarbeitete und aktualisierte Auflage},
  location = {Wiesbaden},
  subtitle = {Lehr- und Übungsbuch für Elektrotechniker und Informatiker},
}
@Book{Gehrke2016,
  author   = {Winfried Gehrke and Marco Winzker and Klaus Urbanski and Roland Woitowitz},
  date     = {2016},
  title    = {Digitaltechnik},
  edition  = {7. überarbeitete und aktualisierte Auflage},
  location = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
  subtitle = {Grundlagen, VHDL, FPGAs, Mikrocontroller},
}
@Book{KochELT302,
  author   = {Andreas Koch},
  title    = {Boolesche Algebra und kombinatorische Schaltkreise},
  subtitle = {Digitaltechnik - ELT302},
}
@Book{KochELT303,
  author   = {Andreas Koch and Dietmar Möller and Tobias Schubert and Dieter Jäger},
  title    = {Sequenzielle Schaltungen, Schaltwerke und Simulationssoftware},
  subtitle = {Digitaltechnik - ELT303},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Test\autocite[31]{KochELT302}

Lorem\autocite{DigitaltechnikFricke2018}

Test2\autocite{Gehrke2016}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Koch, Boolesche Algebra und kombinatorische Schaltkreise, S. 31.//Fricke, 2018.]

Comment: Thank you very much. In first place for your effort writing the tips and link the needed articles so that I can continue my learning process.

Also thank you very much for the effort of creating a style which is what I need!